# what does mean "compatible=true", in changing IPv4 address to IPv6 address in netaddr module in python

Tags: python

for example:

```
import netaddr
addr = netaddr.IPAddress('192.168.1.1')
addr = addr.ipv6()
addr = addr.ipv(ipv4_compatible=True)
```

line 3 will print `::ffff:192.168.1.1`, but line 4 will print `::192.168.1.1`. My question is, what do they mean exactly?

Comment: see this [link](https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/ipv6/current/msg04523.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a simple answer, there's some information on "[IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv6_readiness)" on Wikipedia, which says

> For example, ::ffff:192.0.2.128 represents the IPv4 address
>   192.0.2.128. A deprecated format for IPv4-compatible IPv6 addresses is ::192.0.2.128.

Hence, using ipv4_compatible=True will use the deprecated format instead of the current format. Otherwise, you could of course read the standards (RFC 4291).

Keep in mind that mapping an IPv4 to IPv6 address in this way does not actually mean that you'll be using IPv6. Using these addresses just tells the operating system to use IPv4 instead of IPv6, even though the socket was opened for IPv6.